# How to get first item of Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection

Tags: collection

I am not being able to figure out how to get the first item in this type of collection: `Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection`

without knowing the key, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection` implements ArrayAccess. Try to use

```
 reset($varienCollection);  //to reset the internal array pointer
 $firstElement = current($varienCollection);
```